# Robot location jump in RVIZ window

Tags: ros, navigation, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have a robot positioning problem in my simulation.

In the simulation my robot will suddenly jump place near the it`s original location. Some time it will recover by itself.

And some time it just stay there, which lead to problem of collision of something even worse.

I cannot figure out which part I have done wrong.

I will put the video of my error in below, and I can provide other detail as request.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zq32QXHW6TY

you might skip to 40second to see what happen in my rviz window

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243645/robot-location-jump-in-rviz-window/) by [samping](https://answers.ros.org/users/26715/samping/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-09-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vmatos](https://answers.ros.org/users/17756/vmatos/) on 2016-09-13**:
Where does the position information for the RVIZ comes from? From a localization method? Could you provide more information on what you're doing in the simulation?

**Comment by [samping](https://answers.ros.org/users/26715/samping/) on 2016-09-13**:
I am currently running a simulation using teb_local_planner.

The following url is the paste bin for the .yaml file

http://pastebin.com/SNX6EVBT

**Comment by [vmatos](https://answers.ros.org/users/17756/vmatos/) on 2016-09-13**:
Ok, What are the red arrows? Where does that information come from?

**Comment by [non-conventional_stuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/27818/non-conventional_stuff/) on 2016-09-13**:
there is some issue with localisation... provide more information on the launch file

**Comment by [samping](https://answers.ros.org/users/26715/samping/) on 2016-09-13**:
The red arrows is the data from amcl.

Yes sure, the following url is the paste bin for my launch code, and there is a command after this comment

http://pastebin.com/j8HLw0EW

**Comment by [samping](https://answers.ros.org/users/26715/samping/) on 2016-09-13**:
roslaunch teb_tut robot_carlike_in_stage1.launch map_file:="/home/samping/Desktop/teb_tut/maps/tutorial.yaml" world_file:="/home/samping/Desktop/teb_tut/stage/maze_carlike.world" initial_pose_x:=5.0 initial_pose_y:=0.0 initial_pose_a:=0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you are using amcl to localize the robot.
If that is the case, what is happening is that you have very little or redundant information about the map you are in, which results in many candidate poses for acml.

Imagine your robot is in an empty square room, facing a corner. How can you tell which corner the robot is facing?

To solve you problem, either create a map with more distinct features or play with amcl parameters, as reducing the number of particles or setting the parameters `recovery_alpha_slow` and `recovery_alpha_fast` to 0.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2016-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [samping](https://answers.ros.org/users/26715/samping/) on 2016-09-15**:
Could you tell me how to create a map with more distinct feature. I am confuse about how to add more feature.My map are basically a .png file convert from my cad drawing
I have  try to set recovery_alpha_slow and recovery_alpha_fast 0.0, and unfortunately it does not work in this case.

**Comment by [samping](https://answers.ros.org/users/26715/samping/) on 2016-09-15**:
I have increase my resample_interval:1 to 100 in amcl_params.yaml, and It does improve my positioning problem, but the jumping problem is still happen during the simulation.

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2016-09-26**:
to create a better map for localization, try to add more features, as walls, objects, etc...